# Entity Framework "Update model from Database" dialog bug?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update my EF model from Database. So, I'm using the "Update model from Database" dialog.
I'm trying to update a new SP without successfuly.

Those steps to repro:

1. Right click on the EF model:

[image]

2. Selecting SP to add and click "Finish"

[image]

And after that I'm see:
[image]

3. Now the new SP should be added to my Model. But NOT. I'm looked for it without success. To verify that this SP not exists, I'm entered the "Update model from Database" agian and this what I found:

[image]

**The SP "Plans_GetAll" should be checked, BUT it's not.**

Is this bug? Someone can explian this? how can I fix this?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate, Update 3) with C# (framework v4.5.1) + Entity Framework v6.1.1.

Comment: This is working as intended. The UI says to update the selected objects.

Comment: When it's really add the object to the model, it's removing it from the "Add" tab.

Comment: Not really, consider it adding to the list of items to be updated.

Comment: But it's not apears in the "Refresh" or "Delete" tabs. So, that mean that the SP doesn't exists.

Comment: I agree No1Lives4Ever. It doesn't appear to be getting added. I assume you're not seeing any error messages?

Comment: Does `Plans_GetAll` have a dynamic output? (i.e. not always the same columns)

Comment: No error message after "adding". The output windows confirm this.

Comment: The return value of Plans_GetAll is few rows (zero or more) of a specific table. Always same table.